# push to list of boost::variant's

Tags: boost, c++11, boost-variant

I have the `boost::variant` over set of non-default constructible (and maybe even non-moveable/non-copyable and non-copy/move constructible) classes with essentialy different non-default constructor prototypes, as shown below:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <list>

struct A { A(int) { ; } };
struct B { B(std::string) { ; } };
struct C { C(int, std::string) { ; } };

using V = boost::variant< A const, B const, C const >;
using L = std::list< V >;

int main()
{
    L l;
    l.push_back(A(1)); // an extra copy/move operation
    l.push_back(B("2")); // an extra copy/move operation
    l.push_back(C(3, "3")); // an extra copy/move operation
    l.emplace_back(4);
    l.emplace_back(std::string("5"));
    // l.emplace_back(3, std::string("3")); // error here
    return 0;
}
```

I expect, that `std::list::emplace_back` allows me to construct-and-insert (in single operation) new objects (of all the `A`, `B`, `C` types) into list, even if they have `T & operator = (T const &) = delete;`/`T & operator = (T &&) = delete;` and `T(T const &) = delete;`/`T(T &&) = delete;`. But what should I do, if constructor is a non-conversion one? I.e. have more, than one parameter. Or what I should to do if two different variant's underlying types have ambiguous constructor prototypes? In my opinion, this is the defect of implementation of the `boost::variant` library in the light of the new features of C++11 standard, if any at all can be applyed to solve the problem.

I specifically asked about `std::list` and `boost::variant` in superposition, because they are both internally implement the *pimpl* idiom in some form, as far as I know (say, `boost::variant` currently designed by means of [temporary heap backup approach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant/design.html#variant.design.never-empty.heap-backup-solution)).

Comment: Do you need a container and `emplace` to see this problem?  Presumably the ambiguity issue e.g. can arise just with simple construction of a `boost::variant`.  What happens with `V v(3, std::string("3"));`?

Comment: `V v(3, std::string("3"));` leads to an error `no matching function for call to 'boost::variant<const A, const B, const C>::variant(int, std::string)'` `note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed` `note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided`

Comment: Your assumption is right. I just illustrated with the example of a real context. `std::list` is not mandatory.

Comment: `boost::variant` just simply does not have constructor like `template< typename... Args > boost::vector::vector(Args && ...args)` that dispatches arguments to constructor of appropriate underlying type `p = new T(args...);`.

Answer (score 1):

`emplace` can only call the constructors of the type in question. And `boost::variant`'s constructors only take single objects which are unambiguously convertible to one of the variant's types.

`variant` doesn't forward parameters arbitrarily to one of its bounded types. It just takes a value. A *single* value that it will try to convert to one of the bounded types.

So you're going to have to construct an object and then copy that into the `variant`.

Comment: But what should I do if my type is non-copyable/moveable and non-copy/move constructible?

Comment: I think, that `std::is_constructible` and some metaprogramming magic can help implement such constructor to `boost::variant` designers.

Comment: @Dukales: "*But what should I do if my type is non-copyable/moveable and non-copy/move constructible?*" Then you can't use it in a variant. As for the ability to create such constructors, that may be possible, but it certainly doesn't exist for `boost::variant` *right now*.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can modify your "C" class, you could give it an additional constructor that takes a single tuple argument.